# Dynamically display content based on web address after '/'?

Tags: php, search, dynamic, asp-classic

I am wondering if this is possible with PHP, or if not with ASP since it's relatively similar and I could pick it up quickly.  Let's say I have a text input for a user to search a database; as an alternative to using the text field I want a user to be able to go to 'www.examplesite.com/SEARCHTERM'.  Is this possible?  I've seen it done, but I can't figure out how.  Thanks!

Comment: This can be done with PHP, but it's simpler and easier doing it through the server configuration. What server are you using? IIS or Apache?

Comment: The thing you are looking for is called "URL rewriting."  It's done differently on every platform.  An answer that would be valid for ASP Classic on IIS will not work for PHP on Apache (or maybe not even PHP on IIS), and vice versa.

Comment: Also can do with $_GET ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done:

1) Using **$_GET**

```
www.examplesite.com/?SEARCH=SerachTermHere
```

In the page you can get the search variable with `$_GET['SEARCH']`

2) Using [**URL Rewritting**](http://www.cyberdesignz.com/blog/website-design/url-rewriting-top-5-ways-of-php-url-rewriting/)

Answer (score 3):

You might have to look in to url rewriting based on the server you use.

[URL Rewritting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_rewriting)

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's easily possible. For example if you have apache  server then you can enable mod rewrite and write one rule to redirect all such requests to your script in a variable and it will then handle accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you have two options.

1. Using URL Rewritting in your server configuration.
2. Using $_GET global. Everything in URL after your actual page address is available through $_GET.

This goes a bit beyond your question but might prove to be *very* useful. Even though it is a framework, you might want to look at [Symfony 2 routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) for ideas how to implement it. Specifically at "Under The Hood" section. You can even explore their routing code on [github](https://github.com/symfony). Applications made in it have **exactly** the form you are searching for (content displaying based on $_GET data).